# How to select and zoom to a layer in QGIS using Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qgis

I am using QGIS 2.8.1, and I want to select the shapefile called 'tempshpfile' and zoom to layer on that polygon shapefile.

My code is:

```
import ogr,os
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
import glob
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer

Processing.initialize()
Processing.updateAlgsList()

# Add array of address below

allFiles = ["C:/Shapefiles/Map_0077421.shp"]
filesLen = len(allFiles)

TexLayer = "C:/Texas_NAD27/Texas_NAD27.shp"

for lop in range(filesLen):
    wb = QgsVectorLayer(allFiles[lop], 'tempshpfile', 'ogr')
    wbTex = QgsVectorLayer(TexLayer, 'TexasGrid', 'ogr')
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(wb)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(wbTex)
```

Comment: This may help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91011/how-to-select-and-zoom-in-features-from-a-qgis-python-plugin/126532

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `wb`  layer is already registered just activate the layer after the loop:

```
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(wb)
```

And zoom to the extent of the active layer:

```
qgis.utils.iface.zoomToActiveLayer()
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works, but I found that I need to add a wait time for python to load the shapefile first by using QTimer.